# Is it possible Server.MapPath anywhere else bau in the page class?

Tags: asp.net

I've been using the same method called **CheckIfImageExiste(string virtualPath, string finename)** on 3 pages now because the method contains the method **Server.MapPath**.

The method is supposed to receive a virtual path and image file's name and check if the the image is in the right folder. So when the method receive the parameter, it needs to translate it into a physical path.

in a code behind, I can do something like:

`string physicalPath = Server.MapPath(virtualPath);`

But, if I decide to move **CheckIfImageExiste()** to another class so that it can be shared by all 3 classes, how can I define **Server.MapPath(virtualPath)** in the new class? I mean, what are the references?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpServerUtility should be available:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.aspx

...or you could pass your new function a reference to the page itself.

Comment: I passed the page's reference to the method and it works perfectly. But I still need to know how to use the HttpServerUtility. (see what I wrote to BJ Sadie)

Comment: I'm confused about the error about it having no constructor, but I can understand why it would complain - without an HttpContext, the server utility isn't much use.  It's got the smarts to handle virtual directories and such baked in.  In this case, I don't know how you'll avoid passing in a reference to the page or to the server itself if you don't want to access the HttpContext.  I've initialized as follows without issue: HttpServerUtility oSrvr = HttpContext.Current.Server;   ...so long as you're guaranteed to be executing this from a website, I think you'll be fine.

Comment: Now, I was able to execute the same method from my new class. string physicalPath =  HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(virtualPath). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath

Comment: When I HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath, only 4 methods are showing up: Equals, ReferenceEquals, UrlTokenEncode, and UrlTokenDecode. When I do: HttpServerUtility server = new HttpServerUtility(), the intellisense sujests me MapPath() method. Then it complains that there's no constructor for HttpServerUtility. I just do not understand.